# Multiple resque workers mode creating extra processes

Tags: resque

I need to start 4 resque workers so i used following command

```
bundle exec rake environment resque:workers RAILS_ENV=production COUNT=4 QUEUE=* VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=tmp/pids/resque_worker.pid  >> log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log
```

But going to web interface, it was actually starting 8 workers. There were two parent processes with 4 child processes each. Following is tree view of the processess:

```
ruby /code_base/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake environment resque:workers RAILS_ENV=production COUNT=4 QUEUE=* VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=tmp/pids/resque_worker.pid
 \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
     \_ [ruby] 
ruby /code_base/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake environment resque:workers RAILS_ENV=production COUNT=4 QUEUE=* VERBOSE=1 PIDFILE=tmp/pids/resque_worker.pid
 \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
 |   \_ [ruby] 
 \_ resque-1.15.0: Waiting for *                                                                        
     \_ [ruby]
```

Couldn't figure out what is causing extra process to start?

Answer (score 13):

You don't want to use the COUNT=n option in production, as it runs each worker in a thread instead of a separate process - which is much less stable.

Official Resque docs:

```
Running Multiple Workers

At GitHub we use god to start and stop multiple workers. A sample god configuration file is included under examples/god. We recommend this method.

If you'd like to run multiple workers in development mode, you can do so using the resque:workers rake task:

$ COUNT=5 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers
This will spawn five Resque workers, each in its own process. Hitting ctrl-c should be sufficient to stop them all.
```

[Here's the example God monitoring/configuration file](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god) that ships with Resque to run multiple processes, and [here's an example for monit](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/monit/resque.monit).

Comment: I have been through that doc and script file earlier but we are using monit. According to that script, it seems each resque worker is killed after WORKER_TIMEOUT time. Now, even if i do fresh deploy, the worker may still be up with old code. So, at worst case, it takes WORKER_TIMEOUT time to load worker with fresh code which may sometime be a problem. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with letting an existing job that is running complete before killing the worker as long as you spin up a new worker with the newly deployed code.

The key is to send a soft QUIT signal to the worker so it exits when the currently running job completes.  So yes, you can have a worker running old code but it's on a job that started prior to the deploy of the new code.

Comment: One more problem i see with that approach is when god fails itself. As workers are killed after WORKER_TIMEOUT, there will be no worker processing jobs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Almost quitted using god. When I ran it using  COUNT=3 and with two workers, I got a huge number of rubies. Moreover when using resque:workers instead of resque:work you will loose the ability to stop spawned processes/threads with the 'god stop' command. They will still run causing you lots and lots of headache.